# mail () function in linux using lampp

Tags: php, xampp

I want to create a feedback form using html and php, I am using Xampp and linux mint as OS. Feedback form is not returning any error but it is neither sending any mail. please review my php code.

```
<?php
$myemail  = "deepshikha@yahoo.com";
    if (isset($_GET['yourname']) && $_GET['yourname'] !== '  '){

    $yourname = $_GET['yourname'];
    }
    if (isset($_GET['subject']) && $_GET['subject'] !== '  '){

    $subject = $_GET['subject'];
    }
    if (isset($_GET['email']) && $_GET['email'] !== '  '){

    $email = $_GET['email'];
    }
    if (isset($_GET['website']) && $_GET['website'] !== '  '){

    $website = $_GET['website'];
    }
    if (isset($_GET['likeit']) && $_GET['likeit'] !== '  '){

    $likeit = $_GET['likeit'];
    }
    if (isset($_GET['comments']) && $_GET['comments'] !== '  '){

    $comments = $_GET['comments'];
    }
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
  {
show_error("E-mail address not valid");
 }
  if (!preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/+[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/i", $website))
  {
    $website = '';
   }
   $message = "Hello!

   Your contact form has been submitted by:

  Name: $yourname
   E-mail: $email
   URL: $website

   Like the website? $likeit

  Comments:
  $comments

   End of message
   ";
  if(mail($myemail,$subject,$message)){
  header('Location: thanks.htm');
  }else{
 echo "Message could not be sent...";
  }
  exit();
   function check_input($data, $problem='')
   {
        $data = trim($data);
          $data = stripslashes($data);
           $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
         if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
           {
         show_error($problem);
           }
           return $data;
           }

         function show_error($myError)
        {
     ?>
     <html>
     <body>

     <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
     <?php echo $myError; ?>

     </body>
     </html>
   <?php
   exit();
   }
   ?>
```

I am not able to find where is the problem? If anyone can help I will appreciate.
I can share HTML code too if needed.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I have updated my query

Comment: Is it matching on the first field in both files? If so, then what you need is a hash.

Answer (score 3):

This is way too complicated - the root of your problem is you don't actually change `$V_name`, so ... it keeps printing it each time.

But given your sample data this will do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#read the first file into a hash. 
my %first_input;

open ( my $input, '<', 'test1.txt') or die $!;
while ( <$input> ) {
   my ( $key, @fields ) = split /\t/ ;
   $first_input{$key} = [@fields];
}

open ( my $second_file, '<', 'test2.txt' ) or die $!;
#iterate the second file - use the first field as a 'key' and 
#look it up from the hash we created from the first file. 
while ( <$second_file> ) {
   my ( $key, @fields ) = split /\t/; 
   print join "\t", $key, @fields , @{$first_input{$key}}, "\n" ;
}
```